# How can I make Django's error emails report `locals()`?

Tags: python, django, debugging

When your Django app raises an exception, Django sends you an email to report you of the error which includes some useful information. That's great. But there's one piece of information that would be helpful in debugging but is missing from those emails: `locals()`.

How can I make Django's error emails include `locals()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by including `'include_html': 'True',` next to `'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',` in the `LOGGING` setting in `settings.py`. Now I get HTML reports via email that contain all of the `locals()` info.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#s-filtering-error-reports) Django does include locals. Or am I missing something? Also you may find in the documentaion (see: link above) how to write your own custom error reports.

Comment: I read that too, but the emails that I get from Django do not include the `locals()`, only a traceback and a `repr` of the request.

Comment: And yes, I use the latest version, Django 1.4.

Comment: @RamRachum I think that only decorators are added in 1.4. Reports (with locals) should be available in 1.3 as well, I'm not sure though. Anyway try writing your custom report (I don't know why default solution is not working for you). I can't help you beyond that. :(